# Rails project: NoMethodError: undefined method `identifier' for String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have recently inherited a Rails + Spine.JS project. Even though its topic isn't something extremely arcane (marketing-oriented: people making their own mailing lists, preparing content before sending them, actually sending them, etc.), its implementation however is specific and relies on more than a few Rails overridances (like the one specified below in Problem #2).

I got two problems I need help with.

**PROBLEM ONE**:

To the point: in the Spine.JS app (the frontend), we got a preview action for invoices, which is supposed (and it does) open a new tab to do that. Everything looked perfectly normal until I actually did it. Without too much pointless explanations, here's what happens:

```
Started GET "/me/invoices/22/preview?oauth_token=XE03DFCGyCDYjdu8oWuU9zrN56Z6Wr7eZDuIjCbT&origin=http://localhost:9294" for 94.26.14.131 at 2013-12-08 00:55:27 +0200
  Oauth2Token Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `oauth_tokens`.* FROM `oauth_tokens` WHERE `oauth_tokens`.`type` IN ('Oauth2Token') AND (invalidated_at IS NULL AND authorized_at IS NOT NULL and token = 'XE03DFCGyCDYjdu8oWuU9zrN56Z6Wr7eZDuIjCbT') LIMIT 1
Processing by InvoicesController#preview as HTML
  Parameters: {"oauth_token"=>"XE03DFCGyCDYjdu8oWuU9zrN56Z6Wr7eZDuIjCbT", "origin"=>"http://localhost:9294", "id"=>"22"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 270932 LIMIT 1
  Invoice Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `receipts`.* FROM `receipts` WHERE `receipts`.`type` IN ('Invoice') AND `receipts`.`id` = 22 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8.3ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `identifier' for "preview":String):
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.9.171) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:157:in     `render_with_newrelic'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.16) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (3.2.16) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
```

...and so on. The word `preview` is the name of the controller action, as you can see.

Removing NewRelic doesn't help. Then the error is replaced by this:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `formats' for "preview":String):
```

BTW, Ruby is at 2.0.0-p353, and Rails is at 3.2.16. The Rails project has a few customizations, like the OAuth parameter for most actions -- since the Rails app is mostly a server storage unit for the Node.JS project.

Looking at the API docs (like here: http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActionView/Template) leaves me with the impression that the `determine_template` Rails method (and an unspecified method in the second case, without `newrelic_rpm`) doesn't return `ActionView::Template` but a `String`. Any idea why would that be the case?

**PROBLEM TWO**:

Invoking `rake cucumber` actually yields this for most of the scenarios:

```
stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

The previous developer did have this as an extension to `ActiveRecord::Base`:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    include Documentable
    ...
    def self.has_url
      include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

      self.default_url_options = Rails.application.default_url_options

      define_method :url do
        send "#{self.class.to_s.underscore}_url", self
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which of course, might be the reason. I already tried replacing that (rather obsolete) method for extending ActiveRecord via the `ActiveRecord::Concern` method, sadly that makes no difference. I already grep'ed the project quite extensively, that's the only place in it where a Rails module is actually included like that, so that should be the only candidate for that error now, would it?

For both of these problems, I am at a total loss. I got some sort of experience in Rails (~15 projects) and never had such 1st grade problems.

Thanks for your attention. Any idea will be appreciated, even if I already tried it.

**UPDATE #1**:

As per the request, pasting the `before_filter`s in `ApplicationController`.

```
  def remove_oauth_params
    params.reject! {|k,_| %w[oauth_token bearer_token access_token].include? k}
  end

  def save_action
    @current_action = params[:action]
  end

  def set_access_header
    if request.path == "/users/sign_out"
      headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = "true"
      headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = %w{Origin Accept Content-Type X-Requested-With X-CSRF-Token X-File-Name X-File-Size Cache-Control}.join(",")
      headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "DELETE"
      headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "http://#{Settings.app_domain}"
    else
      headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"]  = "*"
      headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = %w{GET POST PUT DELETE PATCH}.join(",")
      headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = %w{Origin Accept Content-Type X-Requested-With X-CSRF-Token X-File-Name X-File-Size Cache-Control}.join(",")
    end
    head(:ok) if request.request_method == "OPTIONS"
  end

  def set_limit_and_offset
    @limit = params.delete(:limit).to_i
    @limit = default_limit unless (1..default_limit).include?(@limit)
    @offset = params.delete(:offset).to_i
    @offset = 0 unless @offset > 0
  end
```

As for the `InvoiceController`, pretty damn basic:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  oauthenticate :interactive => false

  layout "invoice"

  def preview
    @i = Invoice.find(params[:id])
    @origin = params[:origin]
  end
end
```

**UPDATE #2**:

```
$ rake cucumber --trace
** Invoke cucumber (first_time)
** Invoke cucumber:ok (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:test:load_schema (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge 
** Execute db:test:load_schema
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:load
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations 
building users for ce and ce-int brands
building example CE app owner
building CE beta app
** Execute cucumber:ok
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber  --profile default
Using the default profile...
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
Feature: Creation of robinson entries
  Create a robinson entry to prevent recipients from being mailed

  Background:                                                          # features/blocked_address/blocked_address_creation.feature:4
    Given there is the example customer with id 200                    # features/step_definitions/data_steps.rb:41
      stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
      features/blocked_address/blocked_address_creation.feature:5:in `Given there is the example customer with id 200'
```

Comment: As for problem #1, can you show us the controller action as well as any before_filters that might be run (ie, ApplicationController)? Anything special mixed into InvoicesController? As for #2, can you get a stacktrace with `rake cucumber --trace`? Unlikely, I know.

Comment: Done. Hope that helps.

Comment: @janfoeh I am thinking it's more because the models have `has_url` mixed in them which actually includes the routes helpers and calls their methods as if they are instance methods of the model.

Comment: For the recursion problem, sure, makes sense. Have you tried removing it completely and stubbing it out with a static string?

Comment: Are there any render calls in the preview template?

Comment: No, no `render` calls in the template. I am absolutely sure. That's one of the things I checked first. It's all just simple attribute getters there and nothing else. Also, not in the controller (not in any obvious and clearly visible way anyway), and not in the custom layout used just for that controller.

Comment: Also, on the cucumber topic: I'll review the custom-written tasks by the other devs before me and check if there's a recursion there. (Although there wasn't, 2 months ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: see [dimitkos comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20452322/rails-project-nomethoderror-undefined-method-identifier-for-string/20453216?noredirect=1#comment30642102_20453216) for the solution.**

I am afraid I have no easy answer, but only two debugging suggestions:

For problem 1:

- include the Ruby debugger
- in the console, call `app.get "/me/invoices/22/preview?oauth_token=XE03DFCGyCDYjdu8oWuU9zrN56Z6Wr7eZDuIjCbT&origin=http://localhost:9294"`
- work your way up the stack to see where the string comes from

As for 2: do you use git for source control?

If yes, this is a perfect moment to try out `git bisect`. You find an older commit where `rake cucumber` was still working, and git helps you to find the commit that broke it in very few steps. More here: [Debugging with Git - Binary search](http://git-scm.com/book/tr/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#Binary-Search)

Comment: We're getting somewhere. With or without a debugger, calling the action via `app.get` doesn't lead to an error at all. So the culprit might be somewhere around the fact that this action is normally called from a new tab. As for debugging, I'm starting to try via using `binding.pry` right away. I'll surely let the community know how do I end up solving this.

Comment: We are using `SimpleDelegator` extensions to help us serialize models over the wire (in this case via JSON). I finally found that I have included `ActionView::Helpers` (to be able to use `number_with_precision`). I removed the inclusion of the module and replaced the calls with `ActionView::Base.new.number_with_precision(...)`. Simple as that. I'll answer my own question soon(ish).

Comment: Actually, I'll accept your answer with a few notes (please update your answer with the note that the answer is in the comments):

Thanks to @janfoeh for pointing me in the generally correct direction. After dozens of GIT checkouts and a few bisects, I nailed the reason to be that I was including `ActionView::Helpers` in a class derived from `SimpleDelegator` -- we use these to serialize our models to JSON. So, instead of including the module, I am using the same functionality like so: `ActionView::Base.new.number_with_precision(...)`. Thanks. =)